# In laravel relationships between two models

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create relation between two table Studentapplyinfo and user but one primarykey  data in uppercase and second is exist in lowercase and how to relate relation in laravel

```
public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\StudentsApplyInfo', 'sai_enrollment_no', 'username');
    }
```

i'm tried to this but not working

```
 public function studentsapplyinfo()
    {
        $relation = $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\StudentsApplyInfo');

        $relation

            ->getQuery() // Eloquent\Builder
            ->getQuery() // Query\Builder
            ->joins = [];

        $relation->getQuery()
            ->join('students_apply_info', 

'students_apply_info.sai_enrollment_no', '=', 'sisusers.username');


        return $relation;
    }
```

Comment: show your table structure.